# IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds when working on a DataFrame where rows have been dropped

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I get an `IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds` error when running the following code on a DataFrame where rows have been dropped but not on a *brand new* DataFrame:

I'm using the following methods to cleanup the data:

```
import pandas as pd

def get_list_of_corresponding_projects(row: pd.Series, df: pd.DataFrame) -> list:
    """Returns a list of indexes indicating the 'other' (not the current one) records that are for the same year, topic and being a project.
    """
    current_index = row.name
    current_year = row['year']
    current_topic = row['topic']

    if row['Teaching Type'] == "Class":
        mask = (df.index != current_index) & (df['year'] == current_year) & (df['topic'] == current_topic) & (df['Teaching Type'] == "Project")
        return df[mask].index.values.tolist()
    else:
        return list()


def fix_classes_with_corresponding_projects(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """Change the Teaching Type of projects having a corresponding class from 'Project' to 'Practical Work'
    """

    # find the projects corresponding to that class
    df['matching_lines'] = df.apply(lambda row: get_list_of_corresponding_projects(row, df), axis=1)

    # Turn the series of lists into a single list without duplicates
    indexes_to_fix = list(set(sum(df['matching_lines'].values.tolist(), [])))

    # Update the records
    df.iloc[indexes_to_fix, df.columns.get_loc('Teaching Type')] = "Practical Work"

    # Remove the column that was used for tagging
    df.drop(['matching_lines'], axis=1, inplace=True)

    # return the data
    return df
```

These methods work fine when ran on a *brand new* DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': ['2015','2015','2015','2016','2016','2017','2017','2017','2017'],
                   'Teaching Type':['Class', 'Project', 'Class', 'Class', 'Project', 'Class', 'Class', 'Class', 'Project' ],
                   'topic': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'c','a','b','a','a']})
display(df)

df = fix_classes_with_corresponding_projects(df)
display(df)
```

Now, if some rows of the DataFrame get removed (I believe that the index becomes *non-continuous*), then the code blows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': ['2015','2015','2015','2016','2016','2017','2017','2017','2017'],
                   'Teaching Type':['Class', 'Project', 'Class', 'Class', 'Project', 'Class', 'Class', 'Class', 'Project' ],
                   'topic': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'c','a','b','a','a']})

# Do some 'other' work on the DataFrame
df.drop(2, axis=0, inplace=True)

df = fix_classes_with_corresponding_projects(df)
```

The above example blows on the following line:

```
df.iloc[indexes_to_fix, df.columns.get_loc('Teaching Type')] = "Practical Work"
```

What am I missing here?
I thought that, while I was working with index values, I was safe from that type of error.

Comment: It actually works again if I add `df.reset_index(inplace = True, drop = True)` before performing the operations on the indexes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a logical flaw in your `fix_classes_with_corresponding_projects` function: `indexes_to_fix` contains the index **values** (not the index positions) of the rows to fix. You then select with `iloc`, which selects rows by position. What you need is

```
# Update the records
df.loc[indexes_to_fix, 'Teaching Type'] = "Practical Work"
```

instead of

```
df.iloc[indexes_to_fix, df.columns.get_loc('Teaching Type')] = "Practical Work"
```

So your original code worked only by coincidence. If you had a non-numeric index (e.g. creating the sample dataframe with `index=list('abcdefghi')`), the flaw would have become immediatetly apparent.

Comment: if I get you right, resetting the index actually works only because it sets the value to the same 'value' as the position?

Comment: yes, exactly, that's the reason (need min15 chars to comment:))